# find list elements which are similar to other list elements by 3 properties and then add value from the second one to the first

Tags: c#, list, linq, object

```
protected void AddPositionForPlayers(List<Player> players,
                                     List<Player> playerPosition)
{
    foreach (Player player in players)
    {
        foreach (Player playerPos in playerPosition)
        {
            if (player.FirstName == playerPos.FirstName &&
                player.LastName == playerPos.FirstName &&
                player.TeamName == playerPos.TeamName)
            {
                player.Position = playerPos.Position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How I should change this function into LINQ? Or it is one of those things which should not be done with LINQ? Because I can't find something similar to this problem..

Comment: What benefit do you expect to gain from using LINQ here?

Comment: Are you trying to add each position from the 2nd (i.e. `+=`) or just assign the second's position to the first?

Comment: One of the university project requirements is too use LINQ as much as possible. So I changed sort algorithm, most valuable players selection and now thinking about this function or it's possible and worth to change it.

Comment: KMoussa, just assign the second's position to the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't see any benefit from it, but you can use `List<T>.ForEach` combined with `FirstOrDefault` and `null-conditional operator`:

```
protected void AddPositionForPlayers(List<Player> players, List<Player> playerPosition)
{
    players
        .ForEach(p => p.Position = 
            playerPosition.FirstOrDefault(pp => 
               p.FirstName == pp.FirstName && p.LastName == pp.LastName && p.TeamName == pp.TeamName)
            ?.Position);
}
```

However I'd probably think about implementing `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to use a simple equality operator in query `player1 == player2`. I'd also think about whether I should use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or `HashSet<T>` collections for a quick look-ups.

P.S.

Provided that they always have the same order and length I'd probably use a simple `for` loop instead :

```
for(var i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
{
    if(players[i].FirstName == playerPosition[i].FirstName && players[i].LastName == playerPosition[i].LastName && players[i].TeamName == playerPosition[i].TeamName)
    {
         players[i].Position = playerPosition[i].Position;
    }
}
```

And with LINQ solution would be somewhat different as well (it's just FYI I'd ***NOT*** recommend to use this code) :

```
        players
            .Where((p, i) =>
                {
                    Player pp = playerPosition[i];
                    bool result = p.FirstName == pp.FirstName && p.LastName == pp.LastName && p.TeamName == pp.TeamName;
                    if (result)
                    {
                        p.Position = pp.Position;
                    }
                    return result;
                }).ToList();  // note that this will create a copy of players List
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join them and loop over the joined result to update the list:

```
var joined = players.Join(
    playerPosition,
    p => new {p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.TeamName},
    p => new {p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.TeamName},
    (player, playerPos) => new {player, playerPos});
foreach (var pair in joined) pair.player.Position = pair.playerPos.Position;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your lists are equal length and you want to add value from the second list element to the first list element when 3 matching properties, then the following code will achieve that:

```
List<Player> players = players.Zip(playerPosition, (player, playerPosition) => (
    if (player.FirstName == playerPos.FirstName &&
        player.LastName == playerPos.FirstName &&
        player.TeamName == playerPos.TeamName) {
            player.Position = playerPos.Position;
        }

));
```

Your code seems strange because if there are more than 1 element in `playerPosition` that match 3 properties, then the `player.position` element will be set to the last matching element in `playerPosition`.